# How to Inherit a Class without Invoking its Constructor in Java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, constructor

I am writing a program in Java and having a problem with inheritance.The code I am running has this structure:

```
public class BaseClass
{
ObjectInputStream a;
ObjectOutputStream b;

public BaseClass(ObjectInputStream a, ObjectOutputStream b)
{
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}

//Some other code....

Thread subClass = new Thread(new SubClass());
subClass.start();

}
```

And then here is the SubClass:

```
public SubClass extends BaseClass implements Runnable
{
    //Code for SubClass...
}
```

Then, when I compile the code, the only error I receive is

```
./SubClass.java:6: error: constructor BaseClass in class BaseClass'
cannot be applied to given types;
public class SubClass extends BaseClass implements Runnable
       ^
  required: ObjectInputStream,ObjectOutputStream
  found: no arguments
```

I am assuming that the problem is coming from the fact that I am extending a BaseClass that has a constructor, so it is invoked when I inherit the class, but I am not completely sure. Is there a way for me to invoke that constructor with the correct arguments? Or, better yet, a way to not invoke the constructor at all? Any help is appreciated, and thank you for your responses.

Comment: If properly handled, you can do `super(null, null)` in the constructor for `SubClass`

Comment: No. You need to invoke super(someObjectInputStream, someObjectOutputStream) from all the constructors of your subclass. I have the feeling that you're misusing inheritance. You should explain what you're trying to achieve, what are BaseClass and SubClass.

Comment: So your actual question is "how to invoke base class constructor in java"? Did you try typing your question to Google? Or going through some Java basics tutorial? (Sorry for the tone, but this *is* very basic Java, and SO tries not to be "please read the docs for me" site, at least for this basic stuff).

Comment: Yes, I Googled it several times, the closest I got to these answers were using super(a, b) which just throws more errors. I have gone through Java basics courses and, perhaps to your surprise, inheritance generally isn't covered in "the basics". Yes, Oracle does cover it extensively in their documentation, but their page on inheritance does not even mention to "super" keyword. While this is a simple problem, don't assume that I somehow missed the paragraphs of "make sure you look online for an answer first" That is thrown at you before you post a question.

Comment: Hmm https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html. There is a **section** in the inheritance tutorial dedicated to super. Generally when googling for "java tutorial <something>", the first result is the tutorial about how using <something> in Java.

Comment: I was referring specifically to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html , and it is a little difficult to find a page about super when you weren't exactly looking for that specific keyword. If I had known that the super keyword would be the answer to my problem, I would have looked up a tutorial on how to use it. However, I didn't, so I didn't know that I should research it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subclass should have a constructor that takes in

```
ObjectInputStream a, ObjectOutputStream b
```

and than pass it to the base class using

```
super(a, b):
```

I believe it would look like this:

```
class Subclass extends BaseClass {
    SubClass(ObjectInputStream a, ObjectOutputStream b) {
        super(a, b);
    }
}
```

EDIT---
You can't 'not call' constructor. Even if base class has default constructor (no arguments), it will be implicitly called from your sub class.

Answer (score 0):

The base class has no default constructor, witch implies that it must receive one `ObjectInputStream` and one `ObjectOutputStream`. So, `SubClass` must have a constructor like this, or one that call `super`, passing the arguments. I would like you to:

1. Review your inheritance
2. See if Base Class could have a default constructor
3. Create a default constructor in `SubClass` passing null to `super` -> `super(null,null)`
4. Create a default constructor in `SubClass` passing the two objects required

There's is no way to **not** call the parent constructor. The compiler automagically adds the call `super` to you.

Comment: Even if it has a "constructor like this", that constructor must invoke super() and pass the arguments.

Comment: Yes, I know, I was explaining it

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a call for `super` - the parent cunstractor:

```
public SubClass extends BaseClass implements Runnable
{
    //must implement the following contractor:
    public SubClass(ObjectInputStream a, ObjectOutputStream b /*some other parameters*/){
        super(a,b);
    }

// the rest of the code.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea behind inheritance is that the public methods and variables of the Superclass will be available in the Subclass. (There is more to it than just this statement, but this should suffice for now). So in your case, when you extend the BaseClass to the SubClass, you have the two variables ( ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream) available to you in the SubClass.

Thus you HAVE to provide them with some initial values when you create an Object of the SubClass. Hence you should add the following constructor to your SubClass.

```
    public SubClass(ObjectInputStream a,ObjectOutputStream b){
         super(a,b); // The order in super should be same as the order of arguments in your BaseClass constructor! Make a not of this.
    }
```

Note: The order of arguments in the super() method is important!

Answer (score -1):

When you create a class that inherits from another class, one of the implications is that you are going to depend on some code in the base class. That means you need to setup the base class properly. Since your base class has only that one constructor that takes parameters, your class needs to provide a constructor that takes the same parameters so it can initialize its base class. So you need to add an additional constructor that takes the same parameters as the base class.

Comment: No. You need to invoke the super constructor with valid arguments. Whether you make that from a constructor taking the same parameters or not is irrelevant. And a constructor doesn't initialize the class. It initializes the object. And finally, adding an additional constructor isn't what you need to do. All constructors must call the super constructor.